# laravel passport:install (The conversion of a nvarchar data type into a datetime data type has created a value of ur out of bounds)

Tags: php, sql, laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

**when try with command php artisan passport:install i get this error :**

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The conv
ersion of a nvarchar data type into a datetime data type has created a value of
ur out of bounds.
```